# Как объединить 2 массива в один?

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет, есть 2 массива. Первый `$attr_type`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Цвет
    [4] => Материал
    [6] => Размер
)
```

Второй: `$attr_value`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Черный
            [1] => Белый
            [2] => Красный глянец
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Мульти
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Винил
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Винил
        )

)
```

Как совместить массивы по ключам первого, чтобы из второго вытащились только вложенные массивы?

Как это примерно должно выглядеть:

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array
      (
          [Цвет] => Array
              (
                  [0] => Черный
                  [1] => Белый
                  [2] => Красный глянец
              )

      )

  [4] => Array
      (
          [Материал] => Array
              (
                  [0] => Винил
              )

      )

  [6] => Array
      (
          [Размер] => Array
              (
              )

      )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$attr = [1 => 'Цвет', 4 => 'Материал', 6 => 'Размер'];

$values = [
    1 => ['Черный', 'Белый', 'Красный глянец'],
    2 => ['Мульти'],
    4 => ['Винил'],
    5 => ['Винил']
];

foreach ($attr as $k => $v) {
    $array[$k][$v] = (isset($values[$k])) ? $values[$k] : null;
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо)

Comment: @МакСкири, рад помочь)